# Using the data retrieved, create an array using the map method to return just the title of every item and print the result in the console

Tags: json, api

Using the data retrieved, create an array using the map method to return just the title of every item and print the result in the console.

Code:

fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos').then(response => response.json()).then(data => {console.log(data)})

fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos').then(response => response.json()).then(data => {console.log(data)})
Using the data retrieved, create an array using the map method to return just the title of every item and print the result in the console.

Answer (score 1):

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos').then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
   data.map((elem) => {
    return elem.title 
  })
})
```

You store the result (of data.map) in whatever variable you like (it returns an array)
Basically just returning the title of the object using Map().